# Determining Which Parameters are Invariant in the Least Squares Solution Space of an Inconsistent Underdetermined System of Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have a system of equations that is both underdetermined (i.e. there are more parameters than equations) and inconsistent (i.e. there are no solutions). I want to use least squares to obtain parameter settings that come closest to satisfying this system. Presumably there will be a whole space of least squares solutions because the system is underdetermined. How can I tell which parameters will vary within the least squares solution space and which will be invariant?

Here is a simple example system having the properties I described.

$9a - 18b + 3c - 4d = 100$

$9a - 18b + 3c - 4d = -50$

$6d + 5e = -25$

$3d - 4e = 62$

Comment: You could manually constrain some parameters to take certain values, so that the system is identified (parameters to be estimated=number of equations). That is, you decide which will be invariant.

Comment: @Nameless Thanks nameless.  What I am asking though is how to tell what will not vary if I run least squares on the system as is, with no additional constraints. For instance, I suspect that $d$ and $e$ above should not vary, since they are "not part of the inconsistency". I am trying to figure out how to confirm this and draw similar conclusions for a system of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 0):

Given a system $Ax=b$, the least squares algorithm will do the following (referring not to the details of the algorithm, but what it accomplishes):

1. Find vector $b'$ in the range of $A$ that is nearest to $b$. Simply put, $b'$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $\operatorname{ran} A$.
2. Find the solution space of $Ax=b'$.
3. Find the element of the solution space that minimizes $\|x\|$.

For $x_i$ to not be varied at step 3,    the solution space must be orthogonal to $e_i$, the $i$th basis vector. A simple way to express this condition is 
$$\ker A\subseteq \{e_i\}^\perp$$

Also, the $j$th equation in the system will be solved exactly provided that $b'_j=b_j$, which amounts to 
$$e_j\in \operatorname{ran} A $$

In your example, $\ker A=\langle 2e_1-e_2\rangle$ and $\operatorname{ran} A =\{e_1-e_2\}^{\perp}$. Hence the varables $d,e$ will not be varied at step 3, and also the last two equations will be solved exactly.